# How to abandon all Mercurial changes that haven't been committed

Tags: mercurial

How do you abandon all repository changes since the last commit in Mercurial?

I don't *think* that this is the `revert` command, because that will actually update the working directory to the last commit. I just want to undo changes in the repository (added files, removed files, etc).

But, I'm new with Mercurial, so I could be missing something.

Comment: *added files, removed files* are not changes to repository. Until commit there is no changes to repository whatsoever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mercurial — revert back to old version and continue from there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540454/mercurial-revert-back-to-old-version-and-continue-from-there)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do want `revert`.  The two commands `revert` and `update` are complimentary.  They both update the files in your working directory, but `update` also updates the parent revision (see `hg parents`) whereas `revert` doesn't.  If your parent revision was `tip`, which it often is, then either would do in this case, but prefer `revert`.

Example:

```
ry4an@hail [~/hg/test] % hg stat
? newfile
? output.patch
? this
ry4an@hail [~/hg/test] % hg add newfile
ry4an@hail [~/hg/test] % hg stat
A newfile
? output.patch
? this
ry4an@hail [~/hg/test] % hg revert --all
forgetting newfile
ry4an@hail [~/hg/test] % hg stat
? newfile
? output.patch
? this
```

Answer (score 2):

Any changes to your local copy that have not been committed to the repository can be undone with the command:

```
hg update -C
```

That is, update clean.