# revision control: undo changes that were NOT checked in

Tags: version-control, mercurial, revert

I was playing around with some files (someone else's code mounted on the machine, I have to model my code after it) and short story: something went wrong. The page is printing the header twice, the error messages are going haywire, etc... I'm not sure what I did. I tried to undo all my changes, but it's not working. I must be missing something.

I didn't actually check in my code, but the changes were still kept. Is there anyway that I can just get back to the way the files were before I started playing around with them (i.e this morning)? I know about hg revert, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea; Mercurial seems pretty certain that I *don't* want to use revert... Like, ever.

Really frustrated with this, so I really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Revert sounds like the way to go to me. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773123/how-to-abandon-all-mercurial-changes-that-havent-been-committed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that yeah, just go ahead and use revert, that's what you want to do in this case. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540454/mercurial-revert-back-to-old-version-and-continue-from-there) is not a duplicate of yours *per se*, but it explains some of the subtleties of using `revert` and similar Mercurial commands.

Comment: I reverted, but now I'm getting an Internal Server Error!

Comment: Well, *that* sucks. I suspect it's unrelated, though. Revert is a client-side operation. Try checking out a small module in a different location, just to see if the server is working.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `hg update -C .` to reset everything to its original state. That should be equivalent to `hg revert --all`.

Comment: thanks, that's good to know @Laurens! And it turned out to be an .htaccess problem; I had to remove the file. Thanks for the answer!