# Closing a branch/head in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

```
 >hg branches
 default                      210:87d8059250ce
```

and two heads

```
hg heads
changeset:   1:87d8059250ce
tag:         tip
user:        me
date:        Tue Apr 12 18:33:24 2011 -0700
summary:     old one

changeset:   2:fa5abf8b578a
user:        me
date:        Tue Apr 12 18:13:19 2011 -0700
summary:     new one
```

I would like to close head 1 and only use head 2. how do I do this? How can I find out which branch this is associated with?

I've seen this method:

```
 hg up -r 1
 hg ci --close-branch
```

but then when I go to push, it complains "did you forget to merge? use push -f to force". I'm not sure why it would ask me that, because I would like to override the changes I just pulled with this new head... rev 2.

Let me know how to do this! thank you!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mercurial: beheading a head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688263/mercurial-beheading-a-head)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this answered it for me. thanks [Mercurial: beheading a head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688263/mercurial-beheading-a-head)