# What is the difference between hg revert and hg backout?

Tags: mercurial, revert, backout

Both `hg revert` and `hg backout` revert changes made by a former revision. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Given the history of changesets:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- E
          [bad]        (*)
```

`hg revert -r B`:  Stay at current revision, but update the working directory
as of revision `B`. It has the effect of a patch that revokes the changes
of `C`, `D` and `E`.

`hg backout -r C`: Update the working directory so that it contains the *merge*
of revision C's *parent* (`B`) and the current revision, preserving the changes
made in between the two revisions (working dir still contains changes of
revision `D` and `E`). This has the effect of a patch applied on `E`,
undoing the changes of only `C`.

You may want to edit some files if not all of `C` was bad. Remember to do
a `hg commit` in any case:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- F
          [bad]              (*)
```

Comment: Answering my own question as I couldn't find anything clear on web. Hopefully this helps others now to save some time.

Comment: Nice answer! My "[cheat sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2565996/110204)" explains the difference between `hg update` and `hg revert`, which might helpful as well.