# How do I abandon local commits but not file changes?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I want a Mercurial analogue of `git reset HEAD~2` (completely abandon the last 2 commits -- but keep the local file changes).

In my specific case, I wanted to abandon all changes since the last `hg pull`, so what I did was:

```
hg clone $(hg paths default) tmp
rm -rf .hg
mv tmp/.hg .
rm -rf tmp
```

Is there an "official" way to do this?

The answers to [Mercurial — revert back to old version and continue from there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2540454/850781) keep the bad commits. I want to abandon them - but not the local changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete revisions from the repository, keeping the files:

```
hg strip --keep firstBadRevisionToDelete
```

Comment: `keep ... delete` looks suspicious.

Comment: @sds: it may *look* suspicious, but it's correct: `--keep` means "do not modify working directory during strip" and takes no argument. Meanwhile `hg strip` takes one argument, which is the specific changeset to remove (which in turn removes all its descendants). You can make it look less suspicious by adding `-r`, i.e., `hg strip -k -r <rev>`. Side note: You might also consider committing the current work-tree and then using `hg histedit` to flatten everything down.