# Mercurial - get revision number if nodeid is known

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I need to revert back to a particular revision.
For accomplishing the same, i am using the following command:

`hg revert -r REV`
(Reference - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459018/mercurial-how-do-i-revert-to-a-particular-revision/3459082#345908))

But the problem is that even though i know the `nodeid` of that particular revision (the one to which i want to revert), but i do not know the `revision number`.

is there any way in which i could get the `revision number(REV)` from that `nodeid`?

Please help me out here - I am new to using Mercurial
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`hg identify`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#identify) to answer your question and use `-n` to report back the local revision id:

```
hg identify -n -r <hash>
```

To make it really simple, most `hg` commands take both the local id or the global hash as valid identifiers so you could just use

```
hg revert -r <hash> --all
```

My followup question is this: Why are you `revert`ing a changeset? To change your working directory to a particular point in the history you use

```
hg update -r <hash>
```

and then continue your development from there by creating a new (unnamed) branch.