# Mercurial: What is the difference between hg revert --all and hg up -C?

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial, what is the difference between

```
hg revert --all
```

and

```
hg up -C?
```

It seems that both commands revert all changes. But what is the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Revert and Update in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506803/difference-between-revert-and-update-in-mercurial)

Answer (score 4):

- with `hg up` you actually switch to another revision (possibly abandoning your current branch)
- with `hg revert --all` you change all files to be the same as in another revision, but remaining on you current working directory (and branch), meaning you can proceed with commit, or modify a couple of stuff before making such commit

it is more common to `hg revert` one single file, and that is why when you revert them all Mercurial asks you whether you are sure about that, or else want to perform an update instead

Comment: yes they are the same, it is an alias, see `hg help update` lists `aliases: up, checkout, co`